# How to load multiple Excel RTD dlls into a single Excel (when the RTD dlls depend on shared projects and nugets)

Tags: c#, excel, appdomain, excel-addins, akka.net

I have written a reasonably complex Excel RTD Library / IRTDServer in C# (not using Excel DNA).

In fact I've written two, that share a lot of code (specifically, code around messaging using Akka.Net).  Let's say I have RTD1.csproj and RTD2.csproj, both of which reference Library.csproj and nuget Akka.dll.

I have no issues when I load C:\source\RTD1\bin\Debug\RTD1.DLL into one Excel, and C:\source\RTD2\bin\Debug\RTD2.dll into another Excel.

However, when I load them both into same Excel, the first one (be it RTD1 or RTD2) works fine, the second one (i.e. RTD2/ RTD1 respectively) doesn't work.

When I say "doesn't work" the specific error message I'm getting is "Logger specified in config cannot be found:".  I don't think the root cause is anything to do with my loggers per se (since it all works fine including logging when run in separate Excels).  I think it's something to do with a conflict caused by the shared code.

My naive mental model before getting stuck down this rabbit hole was that RTD1 would reference Akka.net.dll and Library.dll in the /RTD1/ directory, while RTD2 would reference Akka.net.dll and Library.dll in the /RTD2/ directory, and that Excel would happily load both sets of files and keep everything separate.

However, I must be wrong about that, and I guess the question is: what is the simplest technique for me to be able to load both RTD1.dll and RTD2.dll into a single instance of Excel?

I've been trying to figure out if AppDomains might help, but I haven't used them before, and I don't really see how to tell Excel to load one dll into one appdomain, and the other dll into another.

Any clues gratefully received.

Excel 365
Visual Studio Preview 2019
Targetting .NET Framework 4.6.1
Akka Nugets All Latest.